# Forms that end-users can create easily

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

So, after a lot of research looking into InfoPath, SharePoint Designer, and the like.. I have a simple question. I want my end users to be able to migrate away from Google Forms (we have the free business apps thing, and it is getting difficult to manage).

Basically, they need to be able to create forms that "link up" to SharePoint lists that do some standard workflow things (like one that will email everyone in a specific group after a new list item has been added, and then do nothing else). Others are some basic department usage statistics, which is just a few simple forms and a submit button that then tallies some usage stats for each department. I haven't found an easy way to let me end users do forms. We don't have InfoPath and I'm not sure that would help some of my end-users anyway.

Is there anything that you guys have done in the past or that you would think would be great for a new sharepoint environment coming up? I want it to be as easy as possible for end users... I have looked at [SharePoint Forms Designer](http://spform.com/)

Thanks!

EDIT: The inherent functionality that I am looking for seems to be available in InfoPath (which is deprecated)... I can Insert a InfoPath Form Web Part that I create using infoPath that I assume connects directly to the list in question? Then, I can add the web part anywhere I was on my site. Can I have this same functionality with any other form customization options? I can't see how to do that with SharePoint Designer.

As a sidenote, there is no longer a WYSIWYG Editor in SharePoint Designer. This makes editing sites difficult for power users.. and I assume them that there can not be an option for Forms that is WYSIWYG like Google Forms.

Comment: InfoPath is deprecated, so my advice is stay away from it. I suppose OOTB SharePoint forms, namely newfrom.aspx, editform.aspx and dispform.aspx generated from list columns aren't satisfactory for your client?

Comment: It is the most user-friendly option to create forms though. Well, that would be *okay* but they don't seem very flexible. I'm struggling being able to add the webpart to other parts of the site (like adding a editform.aspx to a page). Also, what if I wanted to include a quick form instead of a long form? Official information on these things seems limited, and the fact that there are so many options makes it seem fragmented to me.

Comment: Long form/short form issue can be controlled with ShowInEditForm, ShowInNewForm, ShowInDispForm properties of list fields. You can also add validation logic to list fields. But if you require full flexibility then this is not a good solution for you.

Comment: So, The inherent functionality that I am looking for seems to be available in InfoPath... I can Insert a InfoPath Form Web Part that I create using infoPath that I assume connects directly to the list in question? Then, I can add the web part anywhere I was on my site.

Can I have this same functionality with any other form customization options? I can't see how to do that with SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that, unless I want to purchase additional software to make the forms easier to use for my end users, that I will have to continue using SharePoint Designer. I have had a pow-ow with a small focus group of people at varying levels of technology skill and only had on of them blanch at the prospect of using this software. After my quick training session, I think my end users can handle it. I wish there was something easier, but of course, we are trying to migrate away from one of the easiest form programs available.

Thanks!